# Storing search criteria than send email

Tags: php, email, search

Lets say that i need to send about 5000 email with different content dailly from subscriber search criteria (ex : Job alert).

how the best way to achieve high performance for searching criteria in database and sending email and email provider not mark it as a spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way?  In my opinion, the best way is to use an external service, such as [MailChimp.com](http://www.mailchimp.com), that has an API you can use and send message through them.

This will greatly speed up your development time, and offload the message to a reputable, typically white-listed, provider.

Comment: does mailchimp do single email send? i thought that only usefull for batch email.

Comment: If MailChimp does not meet your needs, there are similar services out there.